# C to Python : For loop

Tags: python, c, loops, python-3.7

So I have this code in C which outputs the following :

**Code :**

```
scanf("%ld",&N);
long long A[N];
for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
    scanf("%lld", &A[i]);
for(i=1;i<N;i++)
    for(j=i;j<=N-1;j++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", A[i], A[j+1]);
```

**Input :**

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

**Output :**

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 4
3 5
4 5
```

How do I get the same output using python 3.7.x ?

**Tried :**

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A)):
            try:
                print(A[i],A[j+1])
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

**Tried Output :**

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 2
3 3
3 4
3 5
4 2
4 3
4 4
4 5
5 2
5 3
5 4
5 5
```

This is the output that I am getting which is just traversing each loop, printing the value out and so getting the repeated pairs.

Help appreciated, thank you !

Comment: In C, an array declared as `A[N]` has N entries, `A[0]` through `A[N-1]`. Accessing `A[N]` invokes undefined behaviour, which is going to be hard to replicate exactly in Python...

Comment: `print(*(f'{j} {k}' for i, j in enumerate(a) for k in a[i + 1:]), sep='\n')` *cough*

Comment: Pythonic way ! <3 @deceze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the same logic you did with the `c` code, meaning that `j` will start from `i`:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(i, len(A)):
            try:
                print(A[i],A[j+1])
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

another elegant solution is using `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import combinations

A = [1,2,3,4,5]
comb = combinations(A, 2)
for c in comb:
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not the way of doing it:

- *try* / *except* blocks are costly, and there's actually no need for them here
- That form of *for* isn't very *Python*ic

You should try to replicate as close as possible the *C* loop. For that, [[Python 3. Docs]: Built-in Functions - **enumerate**(*iterable, start=0*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) comes in handy (allows working on element indexes). Also, *sequence slicing* was used.

> ```py
> >>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> >>>
> >>> for idx0, elem0 in enumerate(a):
> ...     for elem1 in a[idx0 + 1:]:
> ...         print(f"{elem0} {elem1}")
> ...
> 1 2
> 1 3
> 1 4
> 1 5
> 2 3
> 2 4
> 2 5
> 3 4
> 3 5
> 4 5
> ```

Comment: This solution is much more pythonic (although your indentationis off on your print statement).

Comment: Thx, @Alexander, apparently I overlooked several issues because I was in a rush.